# Singularity of free energy in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ lattice gauge theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm currently reading Kardar's Statistical physics of Fields. In the book, the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ lattice gauge theory is constructed as the dual of the 3d Ising model.
(Note: the Hamiltonian is $H = \sum_{\text{all plaquette } P} K \sigma_P^1 \sigma_P^2 \sigma_P^3 \sigma_P^4$).

And Elitzur's theorem states that there is no spontaneous symmetry breaking in this model. But clearly, there must be a phase transition(i.e. a singularity in the free energy $F$) since it's dual to 3d Ising model.

The phase transition can be detected by examining the singularity behavior of the average of the product of spins in a loop(Wilson loop). But how is this singularity related to the singularity in $F$?(What kind of singularity does $F$ have ?)